# Share button disabled in Google Plus while sharing photos

Tags: google-plus

I want to share many photos from an album. So, first I selected all and then, press the share button at top (as showed here https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1407859?hl=en), add a comment, the email of the receiver, but the share button is gray, it seems disabled. What can I do?

This is how it appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems working now. What I did was, added a name for the Album as shown below, and hit cancel. The next time I pressed the share button at the top it displays the window but now with the share button in green.

Thanks anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue as well and tried putting the album name but still didn't seem to enable the Share button.

The Share button actually is not dependent on the album title, as what you suggested. The only mandatory field here is the **To** field, in order to share your photos properly to others.

So what I found out was that it had something to do with my slow Internet connection. After I reset my connection and refreshed my browser, it all seemed to work just fine automatically. Perhaps some things must be fully loaded first before the Share button can be enabled.